# angularjs controller as with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get my head around directives and getting there slowly, 
one thing i've come across is accessing the parent scope from within a directive using controller as... 
ie i have a controller with this.tab = 0 :-

```
  .controller('EventTabCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.tab = 0;
}])
```

and a directive :-

```
  .directive('createDirective', function () {

      return {
          scope:false,
          restrict: 'E',

          link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
              debugger;
              console.log(': link' + scope.tab);
          },
      }
  });
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="EventTabCtrl as eventtab">
        <create-directive></create-directive>
</div>
```

according the to the documentation, setting

```
scope: false
```

will prevent the directive creating a child scope, and solely use the parent scope, 
great, i can access tab from within

```
   link:
```

if i dont use

```
controller as,
```

however,  as soon as i use

```
controller as,
```

i now cannot access tab from the link

any ideas?

Comment: It'll be available as `scope.eventtab.tab`

Comment: @Simon, it's tempting to use the alias within the directive, but it's likely the wrong thing to do. An alias `eventtab` is specified in the View, and now you are coupling your directive to the knowledge of the View. The view is free to declare the alias as it sees fit - and this will immediately break your directive. You should re-examine why you don't want to pass the `tab` explicitly to the directive (via a property of an isolate scope, or passed and parsed via attributes)

Comment: @NewDev I was basically just playing around with directives testing out the object options / settings, and as far as i was aware, according to the documentation, setting scope: false should provide me with full access to the parent scope within my Link..  in production, i would probably be creating isolated scope and passing the items need in. Thanks for your feed back! Certainly a learning curve!